# Hibernate - turning on and off SQL Index usage

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, indexing

How can I explicitly tell Hibernate to use or not to use SQL index?

Also does Hibernate create SQL index if it finds it would be efficient use of resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> How can I explicitly tell Hibernate to use or not to use SQL index
> ```

The easiest way to force a full table scan is to drop the index. Why maintaining an index you don't want to use anyway.

Hibernate is an ORM tool, it's the underlaying database that decides how to execute queries - whether or not to use an index. So if you want to keep the index, and you think the query planer picks the index when it shouldn't, then maybe you could twist the sql query so that it results in a full table scan, or use a database specific sql syntax - `SELECT FULL()...` in Oracle, `enable_indexscan(false)` in Postgresql, etc, (if such thing exists for your db).

> does Hibernate create SQL index if it finds it would be efficient use
>   of resources

No.